# GetLastInputInfo does not correctly work?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I used GetLastInputInfo for check last input info from mouse and keyboard.
On my system on PC is working correctly, but when I run my program on my laptop it does not working.
I see that LASTINPUTINFO changing every 10-15 sec.

Now, I am writing example program for check all input from mouse and keyboard and save last input time from this device but this time not changing if I idle.

How can I check who is generate Activity (device/program) and change struct LASTINPUTINFO?

Comment: Why do you expect it to change when it is "idle"?  It can only update if there are actually keyboard/mouse messages, and only when they were dispatched to *your* window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Raw Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) to see if the activity is coming from the actual mouse/keyboard itself.  If it is, you might have a faulty device driver, or a driver that is running some kind of internal timer to generate a steady flow of input events.

If `GetLastInputInfo()` updates without Raw activity being reported, than a running app is most likely using an input injection API like [`mouse_event()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260.aspx), [`keybd_event()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304.aspx), or [`SendInput()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx).  You would have to hook those directly to find out which app is calling them.

Comment: I used this [Example](http://joelabrahamsson.com/detecting-mouse-and-keyboard-input-with-net/) for detect mouse/keyboard input. As can I see this app using hooks (WH_KEYBOARD_LL / WH_MOUSE_LL) and this app work perfectly (but not GetLastInputInfo). How can I find app calling SendInput()? I am sorry, but I don't understand how can find app with hooks that calling this functions (SendInput and etc).

Comment: Using `SetWindowsHookEx()` is not the same as using the Raw Input API.  Raw Input gives you notifications directly from the device itself, whereas `SetWindowsHookEx()` gives you notifications from input messages being processed by app message queues instead (which includes injected input). Not only that, but `SetWindowsHookEx()` requires you to write separate 32bit/64bit DLLs in order to hook other processes, whereas the Raw Input API does not.

Comment: As for hooking `SendInput()`, you would have to inject your own code into every running process, and have that code patch each process's PE Imports table to redirect `SendInput()` (and `GetProcAddress()`, when `SendInput()` is loaded dynamically instead of statically) to your own implementation that sends information back to your main app when called.  API hooking is an advanced technique.