# Detecting User Idle Time in Python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, time, ctypes

The following Python code is supposed to print out how much time has passed since the last user activity (mouse movement, keyboard keys pressed)

```
from ctypes import Structure, windll, c_uint, sizeof, byref
import time

class LASTINPUTINFO(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('cbSize', c_uint),
        ('dwTime', c_uint),
    ]

def get_idle_duration():
    lastInputInfo = LASTINPUTINFO()
    lastInputInfo.cbSize = sizeof(lastInputInfo)
    windll.user32.GetLastInputInfo(byref(lastInputInfo))
    millis = windll.kernel32.GetTickCount() - lastInputInfo.dwTime
    return millis / 1000.0



for i in range(10):
    print get_idle_duration()
    time.sleep(1)
```

**Problem:** However, running this script prints out the following when no user input is being made during the execution of the script:

```
0.109
0.047
0.203
0.124
0.093
0.031
0.187
0.125
0.062
0.0
```

Why does the idle time printed out not continue to increase, but rather looks like it is being reset continuously?

Comment: This may be related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327150/getlastinputinfo-does-not-correctly-work

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. Check the second sentence of the remarks [GetLastInputInfo function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms646302(v=vs.85).aspx). It seems, that it works [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911856/detecting-idle-time-using-python) well.

Comment: @DariusM. Does that mean `GetLastInputInfo` function cannot reliably give us the idle time? If so, any alternatives?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the os lifecycle of Windows, so it was just a hint. Nevertheless, maybe [this implementation based on GetLastInputInfo](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576786-detect-when-system-is-idle/) will work.

Comment: You can also try to track events with win32

Comment: Using `windll` is problematic because it's global. Instead use `kernel32 = WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)` and `user32 = WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)`. Also, the default result type is a signed `c_int`, so you have to set `kernel32.GetTickCount.restype = c_uint`. This enables the full unsigned range of 49.7 days on the tick count. As to your problem, it may be related to the fact that the `GetLastInputInfo` tick count isn't guaranteed to be monotonic.